# Is there any way to get rid of the Google News link from an empty Gmail inbox?

Tags: gmail, google-news

Is there any way of get rid of the following text from an empty Gmail inbox;

> "No new mail! There's always Google
>   News if you're looking for something
>   to read."

Comment: An empty inbox?  What's that?

Comment: An empty inbox is the result of weeks upon weeks of creating various filters and labels, as well as manually trawling through thousands of emails from the last 6 years. Finally achieved victory last night, only to be greeted by this garish link to Google News! Pfft, some reward :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way to do it within the available settings (public Gmail and Apps). You'll have to do something client-side (eg via GreaseMonkey).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll look into GreaseMonkey and see if I can develop a script to do this myself. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use adblock plus as well.  A bit simpler than GreaseMonkey because you just click and block.

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to block an actual news feed, just how to get rid of a line of text GMail writes to the page.

Comment: Correct, and you can do this using adblock.  Adblock can block any page elements that have a pattern or ID.  So you can use it to block the div that the line of text is in.  I have done just that, and it works in two easy clicks.

Comment: is right - that's an AdBlock filter rule to hide this element: `mail.google.com##TD.TC[style="text-align: center;"][colspan="3"]`